# How do I solve this function and find its domain?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, function-and-relation-composition

Suppose that
$f(x)= -x^2+1$ and   $g(x)= \sqrt{x}$.   How do we find $f \circ g$ 
and $g \circ f$ and their domains?

Comment: If any of the answeres below were useful to you, then you should [upvote](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) all answers you find useful and [accept](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the one that was most useful to you. It is a way to show that you have found the answer to your question and it shows your appreciation. Now it seems like you still need help. If answers are not useful to you, then it helps if you say why not. This helps others to help you. For more information [read this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: For the first one, recall that

$$(f \circ g)(x) = f(g(x))$$

So $x$ has to be in the domain of $g$, and $g(x)$ has to be in the domain of $f$. The domain of the square root function is $[0, \infty)$, but $f$'s domain is everything.

Now to find the function, just evaluate $f(g(x))$:

$$f(g(x)) = -(g(x))^2 + 1 - -(\sqrt{x})^2 + 1 = -x + 1$$